# Handling posted JSON value in .NET

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

All,

I am working on a web service that listens for posts with a JSON payload.
I have created a web app project in Visual Studio 2015, which provides a stubbed out API controller. When I send a test to the POST handler, the value received is null in the controller even though I am sending a JSON payload.

What am I doing wrong, here?

I suspect there is some type of binding I need, in my POST named "value", but since I am receiving a raw JSON payload, I cannot really affect the binding.

**The payload that I am sending**
[image]

**Returns null in "value" param value**
[image]

Comment: For future reference don't post pictures of the code. include the code as a [mcve] so that the problem can be reproduced and better answers can be provided. Saves those trying to help you with having to write everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a model to store the data being sent.

```
public class Payload {
    public string type { get; set;}
    public string id { get; set;}
    public long creates_at { get; set;}
    public long updated_at { get; set;}
    public string service_type { get; set;}
    public string[] topics { get; set;}
    public string url { get; set;}
    public bool active { get; set;}
    public string hub_secret { get; set;}
}
```

And update the controller action to accept the payload

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController {
    //POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody] Payload value) {...}    
}
```

This assumes also that you are using the default convention-based route temaplate `api/{controller}/{id}`

Comment: That was what I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to put [System.Web.Http.HttpPost] attribute in your action/method